# How to call a NODEJS function from php/symfony

Tags: php, node.js, symfony

I am using nodejs package gps-tracking to develop a gps tracking system. My web interface is in symfony/ PHP. I would like to know  how i can send any command ( e.g.  Setting Geo fence, Send command to switch of the ignition) to the device using my web interface to the device using the nodejs server. i saw a method `this.send_to = function(device_id, msg)`. But  would like to understand how i can invoke this method from the PHP /symfony platform.

Please suggest.

Comment: You have two servers, one running apache/php/symfony and the other one node.js?

Comment: You need to explain better your setup. The fact that you want to use GPS tracking seems irrelevant to your problem. You want to make a NodeJS and PHP server speak together, it that it? which package does `this.sent_to` comes?

Comment: Hi All,    Yes i am using two servers  one for the symphony and the other for the node.js and i would like to call the node.js method from the symfony/php  code.  This is the package which i am using https://github.com/freshworkstudio/gps-tracking-nodejs . the method  this .sent_to in  inside the lib/main.js .

Comment: You can just implement a simple API method in node and call it from symfony. Remember about security.